# coloring the static control in select-for-folder dialog that is without the WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC which this dialog window doesn't receive

Tags: c++, winapi, controls

I managed to draw a rectangle in this control but there are two problems. First is that the white rectangle is shown after moving the select folder dialog around with a mouse. I know that the problem here is to hook up to the right message. I've chosen WM_ERASEBKGND that is fired when dialog window is created but then it has no effect, it must be called when portion of the control not shown before is back on screen, so I must drag the window to the edge so part of the control is not visible and drag it back, then the white rectangle is shown. But there second problem emerges. It also covers text of the control.

So here's my try, any ideas ?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlobj.h>

WNDPROC origStaticProc;
LRESULT CALLBACK myStaticProc( HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
  switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_ERASEBKGND: {
      HDC dc = GetDC(hWnd);
      RECT clientRect;
      GetClientRect(hWnd,&clientRect);
      FillRect(dc, &clientRect, (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH));
      ReleaseDC(hWnd, dc);
      break;
    }
  }
  return CallWindowProc(origStaticProc, hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam );
}

int CALLBACK BrowseCallBackProc( HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, LPARAM lParam, LPARAM lpData) {
  switch(uMsg) {
    case BFFM_INITIALIZED: {
      HWND static_control = NULL;
      char szClassName[_MAX_PATH];
      for (HWND hChild = GetWindow(hwnd, GW_CHILD); hChild != NULL; hChild =  GetNextWindow(hChild, GW_HWNDNEXT))
      {
        if ((GetWindowLong(hChild, GWL_STYLE) & WS_VISIBLE) == 0) continue;
        GetClassName(hChild, szClassName, _countof(szClassName));
        if (!strcmp("Static",szClassName)) {
          static_control = hChild;
          break;
        }
      }
      HFONT hFont = CreateFont (13, 0, 0, 0, FW_DONTCARE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, ANSI_CHARSET, OUT_TT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE, TEXT("Fixedsys"));
      SendMessage(static_control, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hFont, TRUE);
      origStaticProc = ( WNDPROC ) SetWindowLongW( static_control, GWL_WNDPROC,( LONG ) myStaticProc );
      break;
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  using namespace std;
  BROWSEINFOW bi;
  LPITEMIDLIST pidl;
  LPMALLOC pMalloc;
  if (SUCCEEDED (::SHGetMalloc (&pMalloc))) {
    ::ZeroMemory (&bi,sizeof(bi));  
    bi.hwndOwner = NULL;
    bi.lpszTitle = L"I should be visible on a white background. Now you must drag me to edge of the screen and back.";
    bi.pszDisplayName = 0;
    bi.pidlRoot = 0;
    bi.ulFlags = BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE | BIF_VALIDATE | BIF_USENEWUI | BIF_UAHINT;
    bi.lpfn = BrowseCallBackProc;
    bi.lParam = (LPARAM)L"d:\\";
    pidl = ::SHBrowseForFolderW(&bi);
  }
}
```

how it looks like:

[image: how it looks like]

how it of course should be:

[image: how it of course should be]

Comment: Can I ask why you are trying to do that anyways? It's just not a good idea to muck with the Windows interface like that. And while we're  at it, the *proper* way to do this is with `WM_CTLCOLOR` and `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC`. Why you do not want to do it that way?

Comment: @NikBougalis: How ? By send or post message to the control hwnd (or I should receive this message somehow, where in browse-for-folder window wndproc or in static wndproc?) ? Wparam for WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC is something called "device context" how to get that ? And WM_CTLCOLOR is for 16b only.

Comment: You don't understand how WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC works. The *child* (i.e. the static) sends the message to its *parent* (i.e. the dialog box) and it supplies a device context in WPARAM for its parent to use.

Comment: @NikBougalis: no it doesn't, this is not the case with browse-for-folder dialog which *do not* receives this message (among many others). That's why I asked this question.

Comment: Really? That's interesting, considering that the WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC is sent by the default Windows implementation of the STATIC control... I'll have to try this.

Comment: This code is extremely fragile. It looks for the first child that is a visible static. Future versions of Windows may rearrange the dialog such that the control you want is no longer a visible static. Heck, it may not even be a static! (Your problem is that your window is not the parent of the static, so it does not receive the CM_CTLCOLORSTATIC message. That's what I tried to tell you [when you asked this question 5 hours ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14707136/is-it-possible-to-change-static-background-and-text-color-from-inside-its-wndpro).)

Comment: Ahh, and that explains it! And I didn't even need to test it. Thanks @RaymondChen. Also, awesome blog!

Comment: @RaymondChen: "your window" what that means ? Which window, there no "my" windows here, only default console window and system dialog, I didn't create any windows here. Browse-for-folder window? That window is not parent to the static ?

Comment: The parent is the browse-for-folder window, but you have done nothing to receive messages for that window.

Comment: @RaymondChen: ok got it. I must subclass browse-for-folder. I didn't know that I needed yet another function for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. The problem is that I didn't know that the callback function used for SHBrowseForFolder is different than the callback for window itself. It came out I must do another function to subclass the dialog.

It's UGLY and unsafe code but it compiles and illustrates the principle.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlobj.h>

WNDPROC origBffProc;
LRESULT CALLBACK bffProc( HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam ) {
  static HBRUSH hBrush = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(HOLLOW_BRUSH);
  switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC: {
      HDC hdcStatic = (HDC) wParam;
      SetTextColor(hdcStatic, RGB(255,0,0));
      SetBkColor(hdcStatic, RGB(255,255,0));
      return (INT_PTR)hBrush;
    }
  }
  return CallWindowProc(origBffProc, hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam );
}

int CALLBACK BrowseCallBackProc( HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, LPARAM lParam, LPARAM lpData) {
  switch(uMsg) {
    case BFFM_INITIALIZED: {
      HWND static_control = NULL;
      char szClassName[_MAX_PATH];
      for (HWND hChild = GetWindow(hwnd, GW_CHILD); hChild != NULL; hChild =  GetNextWindow(hChild, GW_HWNDNEXT))
      {
        if ((GetWindowLong(hChild, GWL_STYLE) & WS_VISIBLE) == 0) continue;
        GetClassName(hChild, szClassName, _countof(szClassName));
        if (!strcmp("Static",szClassName)) {
          static_control = hChild;
          break;
        }
      }
      HFONT hFont = CreateFont (13, 0, 0, 0, FW_DONTCARE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, ANSI_CHARSET, OUT_TT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE, TEXT("Fixedsys"));
      PostMessage(static_control, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hFont, TRUE);
      origBffProc = ( WNDPROC ) SetWindowLongW( hwnd, GWL_WNDPROC,( LONG ) bffProc );
      break;
    }
  }
}
int main() {
  using namespace std;
  BROWSEINFOW bi;
  LPITEMIDLIST pidl;
  LPMALLOC pMalloc;
  if (SUCCEEDED (::SHGetMalloc (&pMalloc))) {
    ::ZeroMemory (&bi,sizeof(bi));  
    bi.hwndOwner = NULL;
    bi.lpszTitle = L"You are about to erase a directory, be careful! (and don't blame me)";
    bi.pszDisplayName = 0;
    bi.pidlRoot = 0;
    bi.ulFlags = BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE | BIF_VALIDATE | BIF_USENEWUI | BIF_UAHINT;
    bi.lpfn = BrowseCallBackProc;
    bi.lParam = (LPARAM)L"d:\\";
    pidl = ::SHBrowseForFolderW(&bi);
  }
}
```